# Searching if AD Computers Exists Using a Powershell Script

Tags: powershell, if-statement, foreach, active-directory

I am trying to create a script that prompts the user to enter a computer name and then the script will return whether it exists on our domain or not, using the following.

```
$compname = Read-Host -Prompt "Please enter a computer name"
    $computers = Get-ADComputer -Filter * -SearchBase 'DC=LAN,DC=COMPANY,DC=COM' -SearchScope 2

    foreach($computer in $computers)
    {
    if($computer.Name -eq $compname)
    {
    Write-Output "$compname exists in your domain."
    }
    elseif($computer.Name -ne $compname)
    {
    Write-Output "$compname does not exist in your domain."
    }
```

This is working up until the `elseif` statement.
If I search for a computer that I am 100% certain exists then the script returns as it should, but when I try a computer that I am 100% certain does not exist it returns nothing.

Correct me if I am wrong but I believe this is because it is contained within the `foreach` statement. However I am struggling on where else to put the "does not contain" statement, or what to use.

I am still very new to Powershell but I am trying to learn as much as possible and sometimes doing it is the key to learning.

Note: I am aware that the searchbase is nondescript, this is for company security purposes but I can assure you that when I enter the correct OU, it works until the `elseif` as stated above.

The next step would be to put this into a `do` `until` loop which will ask if the process wants to be repeated.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure there isn't more code than this? In my testing this code does exactly what _I_ would expect (it prints out the "not exist" as many times as there are computers in the result.

Comment: You should look for an **exact** match => `Get-ADComputer -Filter "Name -eq '$compname'"`

Comment: @briantist I can confirm that there is no more code.

It just lists both:
GBYOR-SDC1 exists in this domain.
and
GBYOR-SDC2 does not exist in this domain.

However that isn't what it's designed to do, it should return one or the other, but I'm unsure of how to format the code and where to put the statements. (As mentioned before, I assume it is doing this because both 'Write-Outputs' are contained within the 'foreach')

Comment: @ReeceAlqotaibi I think there must be something else to this. Copy and paste that code, into a new PowerShell session, and see if you get the same result. For example, how can it print two messages with different computer names when they both reference the same variable `$compname`? Also it should be printing _N_ "not exist" messages where _N_ is the number of computers in `$computers` minus the number that match (which will be 0 or 1). This is what happens when I test your code as well. There are better ways to do what you want, but I would also like to help you debug your current code.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the code provided is working properly, and does not need to be debugged. What it isn't doing, is what the OP *wants* it to do. What Reece really needs is help understanding why what he wrote isn't doing what he wants, and how to alter the code to accomplish his goals.

Comment: Change elseif to else with no condition

Comment: Try replacing `-eq` with `-icontains`. But really, @kuujinbo has the right idea improving the filter